# Why is $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}$ rational?

Tags: analysis

For this question,

> Show the following irrational-looking expressions are actually rational numbers.
>
> (a) $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}$, and
>
> (b) ...

I solved it as follows:

$$\begin{align} x &= \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3},\\
x+\sqrt{3} &= \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}},\\
(x+\sqrt{3})^{2} &= (\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}})^{2},\\
\end{align}\\
x^{2}+2\sqrt{3}x-(1+2\sqrt{3}) = 0,\\
(x-1)(x+(1+2\sqrt{3}))=0.$$

My question is that, there are two numbers satisfying $x = \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}$, **but one of them is irrational**. Then, how can we say $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}$ is rational as a whole?

Comment: Because $4+2\sqrt3=(\sqrt3)^2+2\sqrt3+1$ hence $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}=\sqrt3+1$.

Comment: Additionally, $x=-1-2\sqrt3$ does is not a solution to your original equality

Comment: There aren't two numbers satisfying $x = \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}$, there is only one. You introduce a second solution when you square in the third line.

Comment: @Did Will it be wrong to say: $4+2\sqrt3=(-\sqrt3)^2+2\cdot(-\sqrt3).(-1)+(-1)^2 \implies \sqrt(4+2\sqrt3)=-\sqrt3-1$?

Comment: @Arthur I'm not sure what do you mean by a second solution...

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, shouldn't the root be a positive number?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Yes, that is wrong to say, but not for any deep arithmetical reasons. What you write the is wrong because we define square roots to be positive.

Comment: @Arthur That's the convention. I wanted to point it out.

Comment: @Il-seobBae, there are two solutions to ${(x+\sqrt3)}^2={\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}}^2$

Comment: @SchrodingersCat What Arthur said. Actually, I find your comment rather frightening... Was it meant to be a joke?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Sorry but what it is exactly that you wanted to point out at me?

Comment: @Did Nothing to you. To the OP. That we only consider the positive square root.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat So, you wish to address a comment at the OP, hence you start the comment by my username?

Comment: And by a second solution I mean this (illustrated by a slightly simplified and inherently circular example): If we start with $x=\sqrt4$, and want to solve it, then we can square it to get $x^2=4$, then use the quadratic formula to obtain $x=\pm 2$. But the original equation only had one solution, namely $2$. What happened was that the moment I squared I became unable to tell the difference between whether the original equation was $x=\sqrt4$, or $-x=\sqrt4$. The new equation $x^2=4$ accommodates them both.

Comment: @Did I took your username because, you posted something similar. I just wanted to point out to OP, taking into consideration your post, that what you did is right ( $\sqrt{}$ is defined as $+\sqrt{}$), but if he considered $\sqrt{}$ as $-\sqrt{}$, then he would get the wrong result. That is what I showed.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat OK. Please try to be less confusing next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{3}+3}=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{3})^2}=1+\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 2):

A classical trap: when you square the members of an equation, you introduce alien solutions.

Going from $$x+a=b$$ to $$x^2+2ax+a^2=b,$$

you introduce

$$x+a=-b$$

that has noting to do with the original problem.

In the given question, the irrational parts of $a$ and $b$ cancel each other in $b-a$, but not in $-b-a$.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your written
note that $$\bf{x = \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{12}}-\sqrt{3} > 0}$$
$$\begin{align} x &= \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}-\sqrt{3},\\
x+\sqrt{3} &= \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}},\\
(x+\sqrt{3})^{2} &= (\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}})^{2},\\
\end{align}\\
x^{2}+2\sqrt{3}x-(1+2\sqrt{3}) = 0,\\
(x-1)(x+(1+2\sqrt{3}))=0.$$ now you have two roots ,but  $\bf{x >0}$
so
$$x-1=0 \to x=1 \checkmark \\x=-1-2\sqrt 3 <0 \times$$